# Connect Android App to AWS dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i am trying to connect my android app to AWS dynamoDB. I followed

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLYt0.png)

But when I try to run it I get:

```
09-15 16:12:12.290  24313-24313/com.example.jan.tracestest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: null

Caused by: java.io.IOException
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:87)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
```

For the last two days i went over it again and again but I don't get it. Does anyone have some hints?

thx

this is the exception object giving me no hints...[image]

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator? Can you confirm there is network connectivity / not running this on the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to Raymond Lin

I did try to run it on the main thread. Now i do it with a Asynctask and it works.